# Gosu::Song in Ruby only playing first note

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm trying to write a simple game in Ruby (ver 2.2.6) on Windows. I installed the Gosu gem to handle the audio, and I have a soundtrack file that I would like to play:

```
@soundtrack = Gosu::Song.new("theme.ogg")
```

I cannot use Sample, because I need to be able to pause.

```
 def play_soundtrack
    @soundtrack.play(looping = true)
  end

  def pause_soundtrack
    print "Paused "
    @soundtrack.pause
  end
```

Running this only plays the first note of the theme, and then no sound will play. Gosu::Sample still works as it should, so I'm not sure what could be wrong with my use of Gosu::Song.

Comment: Use the code block option (shown as pair of curly brackets {} on top of text editor when you input your question) to highlight the code pieces in your questions. That will improve the readability of your questions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, this was my very first question.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Gosu right now, `Song#play` does not work without a window. Because Gosu does not use a background thread to play audio, there is an internal `Song::update()` method that needs to be called periodically to keep the song playing. `Gosu::Window#show` [does this once per tick](https://github.com/gosu/gosu/blob/v0.11.3/src/Window.cpp#L264). There is no way to directly call this method from Ruby. The only workaround is to show a tiny window while audio is playing.

I've opened [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/gosu/gosu/issues/390) because this should either be documented or fixed.